# I'd like to make code that dynamically creates overlayed images in a dynamically created container

Tags: javascript, image, dynamic, containers

can you tell me how to have the following code make multiple images that are layered over one another?  Like if I wanted to sometimes have this code post an image1.png with image2.png overlayed over it, but with other if statements true it would post image1.png with image3.png overlayed over it?

```
// create the images:
var container = document.getElementById("container");
for (var i=0;i<3;i++) {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150";
  img.classList.add("img");
  container.appendChild(img);
}

document.querySelectorAll(".img").forEach(function(img,i) {
  img.id="image--"+i; // makes more sense to do that in the creation part too
})

document.getElementById('image--1').src = "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=Image1";
<div id="container"></div>
```

I tried this code but I couldn't figure out a way to make images that overlay one another, it just posts them one after another.

I want to keep using this code because it always posts directly under the most recently created image, making a column of images on your webpage which is exactly the aesthetic I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you'll just have to target the image with onclick or onmouseover and set the zindex accordingly.
for example:
image1.addEventListner('click', ()=>{image1.style.zIndex = '5' image2.style.zIndex = '3' image3.style.zIndex = '1'}

Comment: I'd like to not have to click or hover a mouse over the image for the images to stack over one another.  So I tried taking your code out of the event listener, using it like so:
image1.style.zIndex = '5';
But it read image0 as null because I need to target image--0

So I tried this isntead
document.getElementById('image--0').style.zIndex = '5';
document.getElementById('image--1').style.zIndex = '1';
And it seems to be working because there's no error codes popping up, BUT it still just posts the images one after another in a collumn instead of posting them one ontop of another.

Comment: I tried this but it still didn't fix the problem with the images coming in as columns instead of stacking ontop of one another
document.getElementById('image--1').style.top = 'image--0.top';

Answer (score 0):

So I fiddled with it a whole lot and found out that I had to give image0 absolute positioning first and then everything would be hunky-dory with changing the styles of the subsequent images so they lay ontop of image0.

I tested it and it worked great.  Batfreakseyes goes right ontop of batfreak.